# PageRequestManagerParserErrorException after removed some html from page

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I want to during the page render remove some html from the page (don't ask why).

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
            {
                var textWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(streamWriter);
                base.Render(textWriter);
                textWriter.Flush();
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
                {
                    var text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Regex r = new Regex("<option .+?</option>");
                    text = r.Replace(text, "");
                    writer.Write(text);
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            memoryStream.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

Unfortunatelly I've got the PageRequestManagerParserErrorException exception from the update panel located on this page. How can I achieve the result I want without getting the error?

Comment: check this links
http://dotnetdebug.net/2006/12/28/syswebformspagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception/

http://pohee.com/general/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-in-ms-ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to create a custom control which derived from GridView in this example and used this code in the Render method of this control, not on the page where control is used.